# TypeScript Promise definition generic syntax

Tags: typescript, promise, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I do't quite understand `Promise` definition of `TypeScript` as below:

```js
/**
 * Represents the completion of an asynchronous operation
 */
interface Promise<T> {
    /**
     * Attaches callbacks for the resolution and/or rejection of the Promise.
     * @param onfulfilled The callback to execute when the Promise is resolved.
     * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
     * @returns A Promise for the completion of which ever callback is executed.
     */
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>;

    /**
     * Attaches a callback for only the rejection of the Promise.
     * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
     * @returns A Promise for the completion of the callback.
     */
    catch<TResult = never>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null): Promise<T | TResult>;
}
```

I think `then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>` means `then` has two generic types, which are `TResult1` and `TResult2`. And `TResult1` will be `T` if not specified.

But it turns out that `TResult1` will change according to the `return type` of `onfulfilled`. See demo :

```js
interface Result {
    status: number;
    message: string;
}

function foo() {
    return new Promise<Result>(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve({
            status: 0,
            message: 'ok',
        });
     });
}

// here fulfilled1's type is: (local function) fulfilled(out: Result): number
foo().then(function fulfilled1(out) { 
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        return 1;
    }
});
// here fullfilled2's type is: (local function) fulfilled2(out: Result): string
foo().then(function fulfilled2(out) { 
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        return 'hello';
    }
});
```

both `fulfilled1` and `fulfilled2` matches `then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>`. But since I do not sepecify `then` generic types, I thought `TResult1` would be `Result` in the above code, while in face `TResul1` becomes `number` and `string` in these case.

Maybe I take something wrong with `TypeScript` `generic` .
Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default will be used when no inference can be made for `TResult1`. In this case an inference can be made based on the function you pass in. Since both parameters to `then` are marked as optional, this would be a valid call, and will trigger the default:

```
 foo().then() // returns a promise with TResult1
```

Or a more useful example, passing in just the second argument, again `TResult1` uses the default.

```
 var r = foo().then(undefined, r => "ERR"); // Promise<string | Result>
```

If you do pass in a function, that function can change the type of the returned promise, and I think this is the way most people use promises, perform an async call, process the result, return something else to as the next result.

Comment: Thx. If `generic` type can be inference based on `return` type , why these code don't work:  `interface Test<T> { 
    bar?<P = T>(value: T) : P;
}

const a: Test<string> = {};

a.bar = function (value) {
    return 1;
};
`

Comment: @Jess that is different. There is no inference happening there for `bar`. `a.bar` already has a type, it is a generic function of type `<P = string>(value: string) : P`. So you can only assign another generic function to it. `function (value) { return 1; };` is not a generic function, it is just a function returning a number ..

Comment: @Jess in the promise example the generic parameters are on `then`, the compiler need to find the type parameters for the `then` call to satisfy the passed in callback (ie inference),. the callback itself is not generic

Comment: so in the `Promise` example, type `(value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>)` is NOT a `generic` type? I do not understand, `TResult1` is a `generic` type, how can this function type is not generic. so much thx for your explain.

Comment: @Jess it contains generic type parameters, but is not itself generic. A generic function is a function that has some of it's type parameters decided when calling it. Here the type parameters are decided by the call to `then`. Also syntactically a generic function has a type parameter list before the argument liste (ex: `<T>(a: T) => T`, the `<T>` is the type parameter list). The position of type parameters is crucial in where they get inferred.

Comment: I can see that , `onfulfilled` itself is not a `generic` function, and `TResult1` is determined by `then`. Since I don't provide `then` with specific types. I thought the default `T` from `Promise` will be used. Maybe this is how `type inference` works, it can use run-time parameter's type as the `TResult1`, or use the default `T` from `Promise`, both are valid.